# Hide everything after specific character

Tags: smarty

I am trying to cut off everything after a specific character, in this case a comma.
If the variable was equal to "6L, bottle" I am trying to only display what comes before the comma "6L"

Currently with this code it displays "6L,"

{$var|truncate:5:'':false:false}

I also need make sure that it displays correctly if there are more characters "750ML, bottle" should display "750ML"

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If using PHP 5.3.0 or higher, you can just do `{'750ML, Bottle'|strstr:',':true}`